# Get element by id not working, checked in console after complete page is loaded still no clue

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
jQuery("#tdCatalogName").length
```

I am using  above given command in console.Even though element is there in the page ,it still gives zero as answer.Element is unique , I have verified that by searching the name of the element in the page source in IE9.

Only hint I am getting is that, "view page source" in the chrome doesn't show the element as part of page, but "view frame source" shows the element as part of page ,am I missing something? Please help.

Comment: Your current frame needs to be the same as the one containing the element. Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3275816 Also related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5712187

Comment: is the javascript code inside the main page or the frame? if its in the parent, jquery won't find elements in an iframe

Comment: Try $("iframe").contents().find("#tdCatalogName").length;

Comment: @Rhumborl   I am trying it from console ,how do i change the context in console so that commands from console can work their magic on the elements in the frame

Comment: @saket see mgibala's comment

Comment: @mgibala its working ,thanks for the quick help ,can someone suggest some good source where i can understand more about iframes, i am going to google about it anyways

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("iframe").find("#tdCatalogName").length
```

or, as suggested by @mgibala:

```
$("iframe").contents().find("#tdCatalogName").length
```

Comment: The only thing `contents` does differently is return text nodes that are outside elements (as well as all elements). As the search is for an ID, using  `contents()` should be pointless :)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie can you please explain in some more details,what are "text nodes outside elements" ?may be with some example. I ask this because the second part is working for me ,it returns 1 ,but the first part is not ,returns 0

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie, that's why I removed that in my answer but respected for other user's answer. :)

Comment: @Apul Gupta: I did say "should" be pointless. I am now *very* curious why `contents` would have any effect on this code. Does anyone have a JSFiddle to run some tests on?