# Chrome browser console javascript contexts. Firefox cd() function in chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, cross-domain

I need to fill some data on my page. But there is a iframe, so i need to get contents from it firstly. 
I was told here - [How do I cd into an iframe in chrome developer tools or firebug lite in chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5712187/how-do-i-cd-into-an-iframe-in-chrome-developer-tools-or-firebug-lite-in-chrome)
that i can cd between the iframes. 
So, i tried to do it in the firefox, like this - `cd(document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0]);`
And it works! But how can i do the same thing in the chrome browser? Or maybe you can advice me other things, how to fill fields in the frame. I've got the problem with cross-origin domain. 
Is there a way to change programmatically the javascript context like the cd() function do?

Comment: The fastest would probably be to just verify it via Chrome dev tools

Comment: See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5712187/7988857)