# iframe document write to self "Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL"

Tags: javascript, iframe, cross-domain

I'm getting the Cross Domain error in Chrome. Using javascript on a page inside an iframe to  write data inside itself. I'm not breaking any cross-domain rules, per se. I believe I'm seeing the error because I'm using `document.write()` or `document.getElementById()` in the iframe's page and it's causing the browser to think i'm referencing the parent document.

---

`parent.html` sits on `domainA.com`

`<iframe src="iframe.html"></iframe>`

---

`iframe.html` sits on `domainB.com`

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>iFrame</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            document.write('hello world');
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I should also note that I've tried `self.document.write()` to no avail. Is there something I'm missing here?

Comment: so this only happens in chrome? did you try window.document.write in the iframe?

Comment: Tried just about every DOM path I could think of. `window.document.write` `self.document.write`.. nada

Comment: I should note that nothing seems to break, just spits the error out. The contents are in fact written to the iframe document.

Answer (score 0):

Since nothing is broken and it only happens in chrome I'm thinking it is likely a know debugger issue that is likely causing this. Take a look at this post [Debugging iframes with Chrome developer tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3275816/debugging-iframes-with-chrome-developer-tools)