# Open a new tab and manipulate that page using jquery and javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, developer-tools, google-toolbar

I it possible to  use f12(developer tools) console to open a new tab and run javascript to simulate clicks and form submissions?

For example I want to click a link in facebook, but I am on a window(google.com)

I will open developer tools, and paste a code that will direct me to facebook and click home.

```
// window.open('facebook.com')
// $('#home').click();
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Can I ask you why are you trying that? It's quite strange... Could you explain the problem you want to solve, maybe we can find a different way?

Comment: Look at the selected answer to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3275816/debugging-iframes-with-chrome-developer-tools