# Remove facebook app scrollbars

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I've tried several things but none seems to work.

this is my code:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
FB.init({
  appId      : '582678658430669',
});
FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow();
}
```

i also tried this:

```
FB.Canvas.setSize({ width: 800, height: 1000 });
```

but none of them is working. does facebook changed api?

this is the link for my app http://goo.gl/6veSG

Comment: I don't see any scrolls

Comment: i think i solved the problem! i'll answer the question

Comment: I just add `html {overflow:hidden}`
Solved the problem like a charm

Answer (score 0):

In the Developer Tools in Chrome, switch the context of your console (see this question: [Debugging iframes with Chrome developer tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3275816/debugging-iframes-with-chrome-developer-tools)) and select your app/iframe (the name is starting with "app_runner..."). Once you've selected your iframe, run the following command:

```
d=[];jQuery("*").each(function () { width = $(this).outerWidth(true); if (width > 810) d.push({node: this, width: width}); }); console.log(d)
```

What it does is:

1. Select all the elements of your page
2. for each one, computing the width (including the margins, see [outerWidth jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/outerWidth/)) and then if the element width is greater than the facebook iframe (810px), it's adding it to the array `d`.
3. Inspect the array `d` and browse through all your elements.

(In your case, the issue is coming from the `ul` tag that is defined with a `width: 100%` and a `margin-left: 140px`)