# how to process an url ending in .txt into an iframe as html?

Tags: javascript, html, url, iframe, text

I'm trying to send this [command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17190974/how-to-process-url-into-html):

```
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.textContent;
```

like in this [script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3275816/debugging-iframes-with-chrome-developer-tools/8581276#8581276):

```
var iframeBody = $(window.my_frame.document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0]);
iframeBody.append($("<h1/>").html("Hello world!"));
```

in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fDCvp/)

HTML:

```
<iframe id='my_frame' src="http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1168960/0001052918-13-000257.txt"></iframe>
```

nevertheless it does not executes; anyone knows why?

cheers

Answer (score 1):

You have a [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) problem. You can't access the contents of an iframe that resides on a different domain to yours.

In the fiddle, you also didn't include jQuery.

Comment: Thanks. I will find another route.

Comment: just for future reference, how should jquery be included?

Comment: The easiest way to include just about any script (at least, for simple tests) is in the HTML: <script src="{url}"></script>. You can get a good public URL for JQuery here: https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide#jquery

Answer (score 0):

this does the trick http://jsfiddle.net/Paulpro/fDN7t/

```
 <div id="example"></div>

 $('#example').load('http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1168960/0001052918-13-000257.txt');
```