# How do I access the global object (window) using webpack?

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, global-variables, externalinterface, webpack

I'm trying to interface ActionScript with JavaScript using `ExternalInterface` and webpack.

`ExternalInterface` can only provoked (`call`) functions found on the global object (`window`). How can I get a webpack module reference on `window` (global object)?

Allow me to elaborate some, I want to have a namespace for the company (`window.companyName`) with an interface for `ExternalInterface`:

```
window.companyName = { isReady: function() { ... },
                       driver1: function() { ... }, 
                       driver2: function() { ... } }
```

The ActionScript will drive my JavaScript. The more fundamental question is, how do I set globals using webpack so that `ExternalInterface` can see them (preferably as exports of a module)?

I've tried using `expose-loader`, `exports-loader` `imports-loader` with no luck. `expose-loader`is ideally what I need, but doesn't seem to work. When I set window.companyName in my modules and try to verify it in my chrome console, it results in `undefined`.

Comment: Can you share your loader configuration?

Answer (score 7):

Aren't you using `webpack-dev-server`?

Because when I try `webpack` command everything is working fine. I'm testing it by typing `window.mySampleGlobalVariable` in chrome developer tools.

**BUT** when I run `webpack-dev-server` command then my window variable is undefined.

I have this sample app:

**app.js**

```
window.mySampleGlobalVariable = 'TEST';
console.log('App is ready');
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <title>Webpack test</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        Webpack test
        <script src="bundle.js"></script>
    </body>

</html>
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: './app.js',
    output: {
        filename: './bundle.js'
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '.js']
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You **do** have access to window object from your *webpacked* script. Webpack does not interfere with it since the wrapper function only injects `module`, `exports` and `__webpack_require__` arguments.

Try it writing a script with a single line accessing window object and then check out the output script.

Your assignment should work, unless the execution never reaches it or some loader is altering the relevant code.

Comment: Many of the files assumes the ```this``` object to be pointed to ```window``` . How can I make this happen?

Comment: (function(){ console.log(this == window);}).bind(window)();

Comment: webpack does interfere. I'm using AMD modules. Those modules worked outside webpack using `this` as the global object but fail once run through webpack.

Answer (score 1):

If you running `webpack-dev-server` with the iframe you cannot access the variable via the Chrome console.

Comment: Sure you can.  You just need to change the context of the dev tools console by changing the dropdown that defaults to `<top frame>`. Reference: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8581276/188740

Comment: I'd like to buy a *facepalm*, Pat.