# Can't access button inside srcdoc iframe?

Tags: html, iframe, watir-webdriver

I have an `<iframe>` loaded using a `srcdoc` attribute, not from `src`. I want to click the button using Watir-WebDriver, but I can't figure out how to locate the button, even in an `<iframe>` with an `id` attribute.

Is it possible to locate elements in an `<iframe>` loaded from `srcdoc`?

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="iphone">
            <iframe id='ip1' srcdoc="<%= Nokogiri::HTML(my html code)%>"></iframe>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: i'm not positive (your question is a little vague), but this may help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3275816/debugging-iframes-with-chrome-developer-tools

Answer (score 0):

If the button you are attempting to click is within an iframe, you will need to make WebDriver switch focus to that iframe first.

This is because the content within an iframe is not visible to WebDriver unless it is currently focused on that iframe.