# How to access elements on w3school pages from Chrome developer console?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, element, w3c

I would like to experimenting with onfocus event on page: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onfocus

I use Chrome developer console (Ctrl+Shift+I). When I try to access the input element by typing in the console:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("input")
```

I get two hidden input elements instead of the text input element. 
Screenshot image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hOX97.png
So What's going on here, and how can access those elements on the "tryout" pages?

Comment: I believe they use iFrames on W3Schools for their tryout pages, which means that the elements are not available without accessing the iFrame first. You'll have to approach it from that angle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@David is right, each iframe is a separate javascript context.

If you want to execute javascript in context of an iframe, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3275816/debugging-iframes-with-chrome-developer-tools)

Alternatively, you can use element picker of Chrome Dev Tools (ctrl-shift-c) and then in console type `$0`, it will return the last focused element. When you then focus something else, you can use `$0` to the newly focused element, `$1` for previously focused one etc.

See [Dev Tools command line API](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/commandline-api)

Comment: Blocked a frame with origin "http://www.w3schools.com" from accessing a cross-origin frame.

Comment: Thx, now it works, I just have to select the right iframe context from the appropriate dev tools menu. My problem now is that when I call "focus()" on the text input element, the onfocus event handler isn't triggered. What can be the problem?

Comment: I think the `.focus()` method just gives the focus to the element but doesn't execute the listeners. You can execute `.onfocus()` to directly call the registered listener on an element, or you may try to [dispatch an event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent)