# How to develop with Shopify's App Bridge while on localhost?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, shopify, postmessage, shopify-app-bridge

Initializing Shopify's AppBridge in React requires an `apiKey` and `shopOrigin`. I fetch the data and load my dev-server up but am met with errors:

> Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin provided ('https://example-test-app.myshopify.com') does not match the recipient window's origin ('http://localhost:3000')

Nothing related to the `AppBridge` works in this state.

I've found the only way to satisfy this error is to create a js build and have it served as static assets through my `node` server, and then accessing the app through Shopify admin. This way the target origin specified will match the recipient window's origin, but I'd like to avoid creating a build after every frontend change. Is there any other way I can configure `AppBridge` or work around it such that I can continue working on my frontend on localhost where I can utilize hot-module reloading with webpack?

```
// app.component.tsx

import { AppProvider } from '@shopify/polaris';
import { Provider } from '@shopify/app-bridge-react';

const AppComponent: React.SFC<AppProps> = ({
}) => {
  const appBridgeConfig = {
    apiKey: process.env.API_KEY,
    shopOrigin: shopDomainName,
  };


  return (
    <AppProvider i18n={{}}>
      <Provider config={appBridgeConfig}>
        <Dashboard />
      </Provider>
    </AppProvider>
  );
};
```

```
// Dashboard.component.tsx

import { Context, Loading } from '@shopify/app-bridge-react';

export const Dashboard: React.SFC<DashboardProps> = () => {
  return (
    <Context.Consumer>
      {app => {
        console.log('app: ', app);
        console.log(
          'appstate: ',
          app?.getState().then(res => {
            console.log('res: ', res);
          }),
        );
        return (
          <div>
            <Loading />
            <div>Testing</div>
          </div>
        );
      }}
    </Context.Consumer>
  );
};
```

A related thread:

[How to use the new @Shopify/app-bridge with @Shopify/polaris-react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55365784/how-to-use-the-new-shopify-app-bridge-with-shopify-polaris-react)

I can get `AppBridge` working with `Polaris`, but I'm now having the same problem that that person concluded with.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on windows, you could point domain name to local at **C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts**

Like this in the end of file:

```
127.0.0.1   https://example-test-app.myshopify.com
```

I think other operating systems can provide you with similar functionality.

Comment: I tried it on my mac by adding an entry to the `/etc/hosts` file, mapping `127.0.0.1` to the target domain but it's still giving me the same error.

Comment: @KyleTruong are you able to figure it out?

Comment: @WaleedArshad Nope, I just gave up on this.