# Is it possible to emulate the Firefox-console cd function and/or javascript-context-switching in selenium-webriver?

Tags: javascript, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, iframe

The Firefox [Web Console](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console) currently (version `80.0.1` as I type this) supports Javascript-context-switching to an iframe through a `cd` function (albeit [set](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1605327) to be removed), as in

```js
var ifr = document.getElementById('frame_id');
cd(ifr);
```

The same goal can be accomplished

- by selecting a different Javascript context from a drop-down menu in the upper-right corner of the Web Console, as mentioned in that bug;
- similarly in [Chrome DevTools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/reference#context) (see also an [older SO exchange](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8581276/11064961) on this).

**Question:**

Is it possible to achieve the same effect while driving Firefox headless with [selenium-webdriver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/selenium-webdriver)?

**Background:**

I have a page loading a cross-origin iframe I have no control over, and would like to access `DOM` elements under that iframe. I can do this in the Web Console, but I have been unsuccessful in doing so via Selenium (specifically, `node` + the `selenium-webdriver` package):

Selecting the relevant iframe and then switching to it with

```js
ifr = driver.findElement(By.id('frame_id'));
driver.switchTo().frame(ifr);
```

gives me access to a different `DOM` than what I see in the `Web Console`: in `Selenium` I do not have access to the buttons, forms, etc. available in the browser when I interact with the latter directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I'm getting the hang of this now. The answer is affirmative:

One can access all of the console functionality (including the `cd` command, buttons / menus, etc.) through `Selenium`.

What ultimately got me unstuck was the first comment on this other [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63699473/is-the-firefox-web-console-accessible-in-headless-mode) I posted. I will describe two possible ways to go about this in `Firefox`, matching the two ways one can access a (possibly cross-origin) iframe when working directly with the browser:

- through the console [cd command](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console/Helpers) or
- through the drop-down [frame-context-switching menu](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Working_with_iframes)

---

### [cd command](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console/Helpers) in [Selenium with Python](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/)

A script:

```py
from selenium.webdriver import Firefox, DesiredCapabilities, FirefoxProfile
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

import time
import traceback

options = Options()

webdriver = Firefox(options=options)
webdriver.get(<url-that-embeds-frame>)

try:
    time.sleep(3)
    with webdriver.context(webdriver.CONTEXT_CHROME):

        console = webdriver.find_element(By.ID, "tabbrowser-tabs")
        console.send_keys(Keys.LEFT_CONTROL + Keys.LEFT_SHIFT + 'k')
        time.sleep(3)        

        scrpt = 'ifr = document.getElementById("duo_iframe"); cd(ifr); '
        console.send_keys(scrpt + Keys.ENTER)     
        
except Exception as error:
    traceback.print_exc()
```

This will

- navigate to the url that embeds the frame
- open the console
- in that console, use Javascript to locate the frame and `cd` to it, switching to its `DOM`.

---

### [Firefox console frame-selection menu](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Working_with_iframes) in [Selenium with Python](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/)

Similar to the above:

```py
from selenium.webdriver import Firefox, DesiredCapabilities, FirefoxProfile
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

import time
import traceback

options = Options()

webdriver = Firefox(options=options)
webdriver.get(<url-that-embeds-frame>)

try:
    time.sleep(3)
    with webdriver.context(webdriver.CONTEXT_CHROME):

        console = webdriver.find_element(By.ID, "tabbrowser-tabs")
        console.send_keys(Keys.LEFT_CONTROL + Keys.LEFT_SHIFT + 'k')
        time.sleep(3)        
        
        ifr = webdriver.find_element_by_class_name("devtools-toolbox-bottom-iframe")
        webdriver.switch_to.frame(ifr)
        
        btn = webdriver.find_element_by_id("command-button-frames")         
        btn.click()               
        
except Exception as error:
    traceback.print_exc()
```

What this will do is

- navigate to the url that embeds the frame
- open the Web Console
- click the frame-selection menu in the top right corner of that console

One can presumably also cycle through the options, etc., but I have not done that.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why it should not work to access elements in a cross-origin frame directly with Selenium / geckodriver.

The following code example that loads a page from Domain `A`, switches to the `iframe` that holds a page from Domain `B`, let me directly access the `h1` element and read out its text:

> driver.get("https://output.jsbin.com/gayeyanosi/2")
>
> iframe = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("iframe")
> driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
>
> heading = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("h1")
> assert heading.text == "Example Domain"

Support for that is already around for a couple of Firefox and geckodriver releases.

If it still doesn't work for you I would suggest that you [file an issue for geckodriver](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues), and [attach a trace level log](https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/testing/geckodriver/TraceLogs.html) to it. We can then investigate the problem in detail.

Comment: This does seem to work now (I could swear it didn't at the time). But there are other reasons I would want more control: how, for instance, do I get the cookies from the domain embedding the frame after having switched to that frame? I have tried retrieving cookies after the switch, only to get the ones for the *parent* domain..

Comment: Ok, so getting cookies for the currently selected frame is actually a known problem. It's handled as https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1427807. Sadly I cannot promise when exactly we will be able to get it solved.

Comment: OK, but then is it possible to somehow gain access to the `cookies` api the way extensions do? Using [browser.cookies.getAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/cookies/getAll) for instance?