# how to access firefox iframe-selection menu in selenium webdriver's chrome context?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, iframe

I am using `Python's` [Selenium Webdriver](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/api.html) with `Firefox`, and trying to

- navigate to a webpage that embeds a frame
- open the devtools menu (`Ctrl+Shift+K` in `Firefox`)
- select this other iframe from the [iframe context picker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/tools/Working_with_iframes) exposed by `devtools`.

**Question:**
How to achieve this?

**What I've tried:**
My current script reads

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from selenium.webdriver import Firefox, DesiredCapabilities, FirefoxProfile
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

import time
import traceback
import os

options = Options()
options.add_argument("-devtools")
webdriver = Firefox(options=options)

webdriver.get(<url that will embed the iframe>)

try:
    <do a bunch of stuff that will trigger the appearance of the iframe>
except:
    pass

try:
    time.sleep(3)
    with webdriver.context(webdriver.CONTEXT_CHROME):
        ifr =
webdriver.find_element_by_class_name("devtools-toolbox-bottom-iframe")
        
except Exception as error:
    traceback.print_exc()
```

This doesn't complain, because it does find an element with class `devtools-toolbox-bottom-iframe`. My problem is that I do not know what to do with it afterwards to access the iframe-selection menu underneath. That element has a tag of `browser`, i.e. looks like this:

```
<browser type="content" flex="1" class="devtools-toolbox-bottom-iframe" height="250" aria-label="Developer Tools" src="about:devtools-toolbox" session_id="910"/>
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63715117/11064961) old answer of mine no longer works, because back then this same element was an `iframe` and I could simply switch to it with

```
webdriver.switch_to.frame(<iframe>)
```

I have also tried clicking it (with `ifr.click()`) to no effect: I see nothing happening in the Firefox window that the script opens (no errors either though).

Comment: `webdriver.switch_to.frame(<iframe>)` this has been change to `driver.switch_to().frame(<iframe>)`

Comment: That makes absolutely no difference: `selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchFrameException: Message: Unable to locate frame for element: [object XULFrameElement`. The point is that's not a frame, so it won't "switch" to it. The element is in a `browser` tag, and I am asking what to do with that..

Comment: See my comment over on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63680269/is-it-possible-to-emulate-the-firefox-console-cd-function-and-or-javascript-cont/67434213#67434213.

Basically you should never switch context to `chrome` when you are just automating web sites. I would suggest to close / duplicate this topic.