# Browser console error from running create-react-app boiler plate app

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, create-react-app

I'm testing a boiler plate react app created via create via this basic terminal command:

`npm init react-app testapp`

and I'm getting this error in the chrome console:

[image: chrome console error]

I have no idea why this error is being throw, appreciate any help troubleshooting.

Comment: This looks like an error thrown by a chrome extension and not your actual page. If you try in incognito mode (which disables extensions by default), does it go away? If yes, you can ignore it.

Comment: Just an FYI in chrome you can change the context to only look at your app's frame and not other frames: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8581276/1086398